# How do I give my instance variable a getter?

Tags: ruby

I have an instance variable which I want to set to a value if it's nil when requested. Is something like this correct, or would it cause problems?

```
class Something
    attr_accessor :var

    def initialize
        @var
    end

    def var
        if @var == nil
            #Something which determines a value for var
        end
        @var
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Something
    attr_writer :var

    def initialize
        @var 
    end

    def var 
        @var ||= 12
    end
end

foo = Something.new
foo.var
# => 12
foo.var = 15
foo.var
# => 15
```

Comment: But that means everyone calling the method wants to set it as something. I want people to be able to call it, to retrieve a value, and get one.

Comment: I would replace `attr_accessor` with `attr_writer`. The getter/reader is defined with def.

Comment: @Andrew: This does not mean everyone calling the method wants to set it. It means it will be set if it's falsy and otherwise it will just be returned.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there won't be any major issues with your code. There is one thing you may want to consider though before using uninitialized instance variables. If you turn on warnings when you execute your var method (e.g. `ruby -w foo.rb`), you will get "warning: instance variable @var not initialized". Avdi Grimm points out that "**The problem with instance variables that aren’t required to be explicitly declared and initialized is that it’s very easy to misspell them**" ([devblog.avdi.org/2011/06/23/how-ruby-helps-you-fix-your-broken-code/](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/06/23/how-ruby-helps-you-fix-your-broken-code/)). So you will want to take that into consideration.

The only other thing I would mention is that as knut pointed out, if you are defining the getter method yourself, there is no need to use attr_accessor. attr_writer would be sufficient.